# How do I set my power plan to turn off the display in less than 1 minute?

Tags: windows, power-management

The lowest setting in a Windows power plan under "Turn off the display" is "one minute".  How do I set it for 30 seconds, 15 seconds, et cetera?

I found that the shortest idle duration time you can set in Task Scheduler is also one minute.

The power savings could be tremendous. :)

Answer (score 3):

All power-related timeout options are stored in the registry as minutes, so no, there is no way to set it to a time period less than 1. (0 disables the timeout).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, there's no way to set the timeout to less than one minute.  You can hotkey this with [Monitor Off Utility](http://www.dekisoft.com/mou.php) though.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a script that calls the user32.dll so that it turns the monitor off using [autoit tools](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/11122-monitor-power-off/) (or something else) and manually creates a timer for x number of seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Download and install Autohotkey from here: http://www.autohotkey.com/download/
Download a small utility called nircmd from here: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html
Write this script:

```
#Persistent
Settimer, Idle, 100
return

idle:
if A_TimeIdlePhysical > <enter your screensaver trigger time in miliseconds> 
Run <path to nircmd>\nircmd.exe cmdwait 1000 monitor off
Else
return
```

That should serve your purpose.
Don't forget to remove the `<` and `>` while inputting time and path to nircmd.

**Another alternative:**
Download a small utility called MonitorES from here: http://code.google.com/p/monitores/
I will turn off display and pause the music when you lock the PC.
The only problem is that you will need to lock your PC manually.

**If you are a coder, you can develop your own utility to achieve this task.**
Refer these links:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12794/Complete-Guide-on-How-To-Turn-A-Monitor-On-Off-Sta
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winforms/thread/ed5d17c3-ec6a-44e0-ad76-a672f403d8cd

Answer (score 0):

**Group Policy** allows values in seconds. In Local Group Policy Editor check under:

Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Power Management > Video and Display Settings

*Not sure what version of Windows you're asking about but I'm referencing Windows 7 Pro – Windows XP might also have similar Group Policy settings available*